# How to publish Dot.Net solution correctly with multiple project reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dll

I have a solution that contains multiple projects

PROJECT SOLUTIONS:

1. ASP MVC Project
2. Web Api project
3. BLL project (class library)
4. DAL project (class library)

the web api project depends on the BLL and DAL project

the ASP MVC Project has no dependence , it consumes the only service from web api project

I start by deploying web api project in IIS 7(by right click and choose to publish in the contextual menu), when deployment is finished I receive an error message :

> the library BLL and BAL were not recognized

I can not identify the source of this problem

can someone help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used `BLL` and `BAL` to web api project. Then expand the `Reference` section of web api project then open this two `BLL` and `BAL` properties and make their property `copy local` as `true`

Comment: I Have change copy local as true and the probleme was resolved

Comment: thats great, happy coding